# Slow pandas when looping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and a set of ids, and want to end out with a result that for a given id, it has the previous and next 5 rows in pandas as a dictionary.

To achieve this I wrote the following code where events is a set of ids and df is a pandas dataframe.

The issue is that this code runs very slowly as the number of ids approach 1000. Is there a way to make this code run faster without having to loop over the dataset?

Here's some sample data:

```
Dataframe

index  event_id  type   timestamp
0      asd12e    click  12322232
1      asj123    click  212312312
2      asd321    touch  12312323
3      asdas3    click  33332233
4      sdsaa3    touch  33211333

event_ids
["asd321"]
```

Given this sample data, I would like to retrieve a dictionary that contains the data for the id (asd321) and the previous and next 2 rows in the dataframe based on the index field, in the following format:

```
{id: asd321}

def get_occurence(row, label, next, previous):
  return {
    "type": row.type,
    "timestamp": row.timestamp
    "next_occurences": [...],
    "prev_occurences": [...]
  }

def get_occurences(events, df, N):
  occurences = {}
  df = df[df.event_id.isin(events)]
  for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    prev_occurences = get_next_or_prev_occurences(event_id=row.event_id,
                                                  df=df,
                                                  N=N,
                                                  next=False)

    next_occurences = get_next_or_prev_occurences(event_id=row.event_id,
                                                  df=df,
                                                  N=N,
                                                  next=True)

    occurence = get_occurence(
        row=row,
        prev_occurences=prev_occurences,
        next_occurences=next_occurences)

    occurences[row.event_id] = occurence

return occurences        


def get_next_or_prev_occurences(event_id, df, N, next):
    current_index = df[df.event_id == event_id].index[-1]
    if next:
        new_df = df.iloc[current_index+1:current_index+N]
    else:
        new_df = df.iloc[current_index-N:current_index-1]        
    occurences = []
    for idx, row in new_df.iterrows():
        occurence = get_occurence(row)        
        occurences.append(occurence)

    return occurences
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it is you're trying to do instead of leaving it up for us to figure out by reading all the code you've put here?

Comment: do you have a sample data? is it indexed by id?

Comment: Are the index values consecutively, i.e. are there missing values or would you know that if 10 is the given then you are interested in 9 to 15?

Comment: The events are coming from a Redshift database and are coming in at the time they occurred. Each row has an event_id but is not indexed by it. For the event on index 5, the previous 5 events would be iloc[0:4]

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
# get indexes of the given events
matching_indexes = pd.Series(df[df["event_id"].isin(event_ids)].index)


# build extended index list containing the neighbors you are interested in:
# the previous and next five
indexes = pd.concat([matching_indexes - 1,
                     matching_indexes, 
                     matching_indexes + 1,
                     matching_indexes + 2,
                     matching_indexes + 3,
                     matching_indexes + 4,
                     matching_indexes + 5]).sort_values().unique()

# avoid overflows
indexes_rest = indexes[(indexes <= df.index.max()) & (indexes >= df.index.min())]

# restrict your dataframe accordingly
df.iloc[indexes_rest, :]
```

Here is another variant (added later, I think this is closer to the desired output).

As before create the *matching_indexes*. Then:

```
# build a dataframe containing all required indexes per event in one row
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"orig_ind": matching_indexes,
                  "m1": matching_indexes - 1,
                  "p1": matching_indexes + 1,
                  "p2": matching_indexes + 2,
                  "p3": matching_indexes + 3,
                  "p4": matching_indexes + 4,
                  "p5": matching_indexes + 5})

# unpivotize and avoid overflows
index_frame = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["orig_ind"], value_vars=["m1", "p1",  "p2", "p3", "p4","p5"])
index_frame = index_frame[(index_frame.value <= df.index.max()) &  (index_frame.value >= df.index.min())]

# select the entries from original frame belonging to the indexes
df_new = df.iloc[index_frame.value, :].copy()

# add additional information
df_new["orig_event_id"] = df.iloc[index_frame.orig_ind, :]["event_id"].values
df_new["neighbor_type"] = index_frame["variable"].values
df_new2 = df_new[["orig_event_id", "event_id", "neighbor_type"]].copy()

# produce a dict from the above
as_dict = df_new2.pivot(index="orig_event_id", columns='neighbor_type').to_dict('index')
```

The result is found in *as_dict*.